# Disble the Maximize button in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

My `JFrame` opens in a minimized Mode but it can be maximized.
I want to disable the maximize icon so that user cannot maximize the frame and can see it only in the minimized or default mode.

Is it possible?

Comment: How about using JDialog instead?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove just the Maximize button from a JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625436/how-can-i-remove-just-the-maximize-button-from-a-jframe)

Answer (score 0):

Use `frame.setResizable(false)`. It disables the maximize button but let the the 'close' and 'minimize' buttons active.

Comment: i have tried using setResizable  but i am still able to maximize the window

Comment: @user3402356 can you provide a piece of code ? It is difficult to reproduce your case...

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your code, try using JDialog instead of JFrame for main window.

```
frame.setResizeable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

> there is no direct way to remove the maximize button off the 
>   Resizable JFrame as it is created by Windows and it is not painted
>   using Swing so U can’t touch this.

so you can replace `JFrame` with `JDialog` or remove the title bar and implement customized title bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it by using frame.setResizeable(false); or you can remove it completely by using following code

```
public class Test extends JDialog {
public Test(JFrame frame, String str) {
    super(frame, str);
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Test myFrame = new Test(new JFrame(), "Removing maximize button");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(100, 100);
        myFrame.add(panel);
        myFrame.setSize(100, 100);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
} }
```