# Java swing: How to hide window Maximizer option?

Tags: java, swing, window, maximize-window

[Like this Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1IYg.png)

Can anyone please suggest me how to hide the window maximizer/minimizer option from JFrame or Window?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625436/how-can-i-remove-just-the-maximize-button-from-a-jframe

Comment: Reading the answers in the link given above, it seems platform dependent whether the button is removed or just disabled. So there's probably no guarantee that it will work the same on every OS