# When the window shows up its minimized

Tags: java, eclipse, window, windowbuilder

so I've tried out eclipse's windowbuilder which i downloaded from here: https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php

And i just tried to make a window with a button but when i launch it the window starts minimized... is the problem how i am starting it?:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    test4 test = new test4();
    test.setVisible(true);

}
```

test4 is a superclass of JFrame by the way.

Please answer!
Thanks, Daniel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JFrame Maximize window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479523/jframe-maximize-window)

Answer (score 0):

**Before asking a question, please do some research.**

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479523/jframe-maximize-window) for automatic window maximizing.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625436/how-can-i-remove-just-the-maximize-button-from-a-jframe) for the maximize and minimize button.

Also you aren't starting JFrame incorrectly.

Tips:

`test.setResizable(boolean Value); //Maximize button`

`test.setSize(int x1, int x2); //Set size of JFrame`